# When does WeakReference#get() start returning null?

Tags: java, android, reference, garbage-collection, weak-references

I want to use `WeakReference`s as part of an (android) bitmap-cache to be able to check when a bitmap isn't used anymore.

My cache has a maximum-size that is smaller than the Java heap-space. When a new bitmap would overflow the cache, it should let go of bitmaps that aren't needed anymore.

My question: When does the get()-method of a `WeakReference` return null?

1. As soon as there are no more strong-references to the object? (and GC hasn't occurred yet)
2. Or when the GC has run and determined that their are no more strong-references to the object?

If 2. is true than I could run into the situation that my cache could fill up and GC hasn't recently run for some reason.

Then even if I had already let go of references AFTER the last GC run, `WeakReference#get()` would still return the object and my cache wouldn't clear it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is it depends on what version of Android you're using.  Somewhere in the 2.3 timeframe, Android changed its handling or weak references.  Previously, it deleted them when the GC ran.  As of some version of 2.3 (2.3.3?) it started deleting them immediately upon the last strong reference going away.  So in modern versions of Android, weak references are useless.

Before this change, weak references were used for caching.  They no longer work.  The correct way now is to use an LRUCache.  If you need to support older versions, use the support library to backport the LRU cache.

After some searching, I think the change was made in 3.0, not 2.3.  Still, the solution is the same.

Comment: Soft references are intended for caching. What's their behavior on Android?

Comment: Same-  they're freed as soon as no strong references exist.  Which follows the letter of the Java standard, if not the spirit.

Comment: The change was in API Level 9. Relevant documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#memory-cache

Comment: The change is a fix, surely? The previous behaviour was incorrect. The Javadoc specifies that it happens before finalization, which precludes it happening at GC time, which follows finalization.

Comment: @EJP - the collector can identify that an object is weakly/softly reachable before the finalizer and before collection.

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I have a large application where multiple ImageViews can display the same bitmap, so I need to keep track of how often it is used. I wanted to use WeakReference<ImageView> so I don't have to walk through the entire hierarchy everytime i don't need a view anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't say they're "useless". WeakReferences are still useful in Android for preventing reference cycles.

Comment: Note that you should not depend on this behaviour of `WeakReference` because it does not work for cycles such as views in an Activity (views reference Context which is the Activity and that references the views). In cycles, references cannot go away until it is determined that the cycle is not outside-reachable. And that is done by the GC.

Answer (score 5):

The WeakReference is cleared as soon as the GC has determined that the object is weakly reachable.

This is close to your second case. However, weak reachability requires not just the absence of strong references, but also the absence of soft references.

From the Java package documentation for [java.lang.ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability):

> Soft and weak references are automatically cleared by the collector before being added to the queues with which they are registered, if any.
>
> ...
>
> An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference. When the weak references to a weakly-reachable object are cleared, the object becomes eligible for finalization.

Comment: THis is correct from a Java standpoint, but not the whole story for Android.  See my post about how Android implements these specifically and how it changed in the past.

Answer (score 5):

To cache bitmaps use SoftReference rather than Weak. GC would clear WeakReference as soon as it looses all its Strong and Soft references which might destroy the purpose of caching. SoftReference are cleared only if there is low memory.And it is guaranteed that the GC would be run before throwing a OOME.

Comment: +1 - I should have thought of mentioning that, after once having to replace weak references throughout a library with soft.

Answer (score -3):

As stated in the other answers, a WeakReference will return null once the pointed object has no more strong/soft references **and** the GC has reclaimed memory.

On a more general rule, I don't think Weak/SoftReferences are a good thing in an application. It makes your mix concerns :

- Your application is about business logic
- The JVM and Dalvik are about memory management and code optimisation.

When you start to use Weak/Soft references, you introduce memory-managed concerns within your application, which makes it harder to develop/debug/understand.

You might want to have a fixed-size (number of elements or bitmap size) LRU cache instead.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Gabe Sechan provides the best answer for Android. Elsewhere, applications contain more than business logic, and Weak/SoftReferences have their uses.

Comment: 'Your application is about business logic' is a bit presumptive.  Mobile Applications aren't always run-of-the-mill web-service wrappers, and Weak References are a key concept in Volatile Caching which finds many uses in performance-critical Applications, both on the Mobile and Server side.